# android : drawing to canvas without stretching

Tags: android, canvas, blur

I an trying to draw a bitmap to canvas. it results in stretching the bitmap. What i want is not to stretch if image small and crop the image if it is bigger than the display. How this can be achieved.

I have a custom drawable that extends DrawableWrapper

```
    public class MyDrawable extends DrawableWrapper {
public MyDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
        super(drawable);


    }
    public MyDrawable(final Context context, Bitmap bitmap) {
        this(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(),bitmap));
}
```

I am having this code in boundsChnage()

```
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bounds.width(), bounds.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            super.draw(canvas);
}
```

This results in drawing a cropped part of the stretched drawable.

Answer (score 0):

```
i think it will help you.

Bitmap scaleBitmap = scaleBitmap(bitmap);
RectF rectF = new RectF(0, (mHeight scaleBitmap.getHeight()),
scaleBitmap.getWidth(), scaleBitmap.getHeight());
canvas.drawBitmap(scaleBitmap, null, rectF, null);

private Bitmap scaleBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        Log.v("Pictures", "Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);
        int mWidth = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        int mHeight = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        if (width > height) {
            // landscape
            int ratio = width / mWidth;
            width = mWidth;
            height = height / ratio;
        } else if (height > width) {
            // portrait
            int ratio = height / mHeight;
            height = mHeight;
            width = width / ratio;
        } else {
            // square
            height = mWidth;
            width = mWidth;
        }

        Log.v("Pictures", "after scaling Width and height are " + width + "--" + height);

        bm = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, width, height, true);
        return bm;
    }
```